# Add a custom CSS class with parsley.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parsley.js

Using ParsleyJS, I have some custom javascript to add/remove a CSS class to an icon based on if the input is valid.  Everything works, except when a user enters one input successfully and tabs/goes to the next input.  When that happens, the class is applied to the icon even though the input is not valid.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cfw80607/1/

JavaScript:

```
$('form').parsley().subscribe('parsley:field:validate', function (fieldInstance) {
    if ($('#name').parsley().isValid()) 
        $('.fa-user').addClass('cta-success').removeClass('cta-error');
    else
        $('.fa-user').addClass('cta-error').removeClass('cta-success');
    if ($('#email').parsley().isValid())
        $('.form-group .fa-envelope').addClass('cta-success').removeClass('cta-error');
    else
        $('.form-group .fa-envelope').addClass('cta-error').removeClass('cta-success');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your want to use listeners on each field

```
$('form').parsley();

$.listen('parsley:field:error', function(ParsleyField) {
    ParsleyField.$element.prev('i.fa').removeClass('cta-success').addClass('cta-error');
});
$.listen('parsley:field:success', function(ParsleyField) {
    ParsleyField.$element.prev('i.fa').removeClass('cta-error').addClass("cta-success");    
});
```

Example here https://jsfiddle.net/acidrat/wqpr4gcq/

Comment: I added

    parsley:form:validated

yet, it still doesn't seem to work quite right.

Comment: @Majoros maybe you can explain what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to add a css class to the icons in the inputs so that they change color (green if valid or red if not) depending on if the field is valid or not.  Your fiddle works fine - the icons just don't change color.  With the javascript code I created, I was able to get the icons to change color except I had one problem - after entering one input, the next icon on the other input would change color before being valid.

Comment: Just to clarify, see screenshot:

http://imgur.com/GRQsjGZ

The email icon is red (class has been applied) before the input has been validated with Parsley.  I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: So you are saying my jsfiddle is working but your code not? If that's the case your should provide more of your code.  Here is my fiddle: http://i.imgur.com/3VqvEia.png

Comment: They both don't work completely.  Notice in your fiddle/image, the icons never change color.  I am trying to get the icons to change color depending on if the input is valid or not.  In my fiddle, the icons change color, but not necessarily if the input is valid or not.

Comment: @Majoros ok, i have updated the feed with a little bit different and more general approach using $.listen

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the focusout as well as the change.
`data-parsley-trigger="change focusout"`

https://jsfiddle.net/cfw80607/2/

Comment: Oh, I think @Timur has an answer that is much cleaner. Although it looks like the js fiddle doesn't use `parsley:form:validated`, but it's probably the right answer, not just throwing on more triggers :)

Comment: i forgot to update the fiddle, should be the right one now :)